# Rows in their own columns depending on their date and symbolized by 'x'

Tags: sql-server, datetime, pivot

Dear All, please help me since I'm newbie in SQL Server. I have a select query that currently produces the following results:

DoctorName 

   
Team

   
Visit date 




dr. As 
   

A

      
 5 
 




dr. Sc
         
 A 
      
4 
 

dr. Gh          B       6 
 
dr. Nd          C       31
 
dr  As          A       7

Using the following query:
SELECT d.DoctorName, t.TeamName, ca.VisitDate FROM cActivity AS ca 
INNER JOIN doctor AS d ON ca.DoctorId = d.Id
INNER JOIN team AS t ON ca.TeamId = t.Id
WHERE ca.VisitDate BETWEEN '1/1/2010' AND '1/31/2010'

I want to produce the following:

DoctorName   Team  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 ... 31      Visited 
dr. As         A                                         x        x ...              2 times 
dr. Sc         A                                  x                   ...             1 times 
dr. Gh         B                                                  x    ...             1 times 
dr. Nd         C                                                       ... x           1 times

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I using sql server 2008.. can you help answer my question? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475893/finding-numbers-of-days-between-two-date-to-make-a-dynamic-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT d.doctorname,
         t.teamname,
         MAX(CASE WHEN ca.visitdate = 1 THEN 'x' ELSE NULL END) AS 1,
         MAX(CASE WHEN ca.visitdate = 2 THEN 'x' ELSE NULL END) AS 2,
         MAX(CASE WHEN ca.visitdate = 3 THEN 'x' ELSE NULL END) AS 3,
         ...
         MAX(CASE WHEN ca.visitdate = 31 THEN 'x' ELSE NULL END) AS 31,
         COUNT(*) AS visited
    FROM CACTIVITY ca
    JOIN DOCTOR d ON d.id = ca.doctorid 
    JOIN TEAM t ON t.id = ca.teamid
   WHERE ca.visitdate BETWEEN '1/1/2010' AND '1/31/2010'
GROUP BY d.doctorname, t.teamname
```

Comment: can you help me to make it the columns dynamic? I mean to make it not only 31 but also can 28, 30, 31?